# Why blogdown::hugo_build() can't handle the Lua filters?

Tags: r-markdown, blogdown

When I use Lua filters to change the text color in **blogdown**, the change works well after `rmarkdown::render()`,

but the changes can't show up after `blogdown::hugo_build()` and `blogdown:::serve_site()`. Can you please tell me why?

```
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: --lua-filter=color-text.lua
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `blogdown::hugo_build()` doesn't call Pandoc. Lua filters only work for Pandoc.

`blogdown::serve_site()` might call Pandoc---it depends on the source file format. See [Section 1.5 of the **blogdown** book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html). You didn't provide a reproducible example, so I'm unable to provide further help.

Comment: Thanks Yihui, I used the color-text.lua file the same as that in your book (https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html). In the .Rmd file I use: output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: --lua-filter=color-text.lua   
Both blogdown::hugo_build() and blogdown:::serve_site() can't render the color change.

Comment: Again, please read Section 1.5 as I mentioned. blogdown doesn't support the `html_document` format. It only supports `blogdown::html_page`. If you want to use Lua filters, they have to be passed to the `blogdown::html_page` format.